# track C++ memory allocations

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, visualization

I am looking for a way to track memory allocations in a C++ program. I am *not* interested in memory leaks, which seem to be what most tools are trying to find, but rather creating a memory usage profile for the application. Ideal output would be either a big list of function names plus number of maximum allocated bytes over time or better yet, a graphical representation of the heap over time. Horizontal axis is time, vertical axis heap space. Every function would get it's own color and draw lines according to allocated heap bytes. Bonus points for identifying allocated object types as well.

The idea is to find memory bottlenecks/to visualize what functions/threads consume the most memory and should be targetted for further optimization.

I have briefly looked at Purify, BoundsChecker and AQTime but they don't seem to be what I'm after. Valgrind looks suitable, however, I'm on Windows. [Memtrack](http://www.almostinfinite.com/memtrack.html) looks promising, but requires significant changes to the source code.

My google skills must have failed me, cause it doesn't seem to be such an uncommon request? All the needed information to create a tool like that should be readily available from the program's debug symbols plus runtime API calls - no?

Answer (score 36):

Use Valgrind and its tool Massif. Its example output (a part of it):

```
99.48% (20,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->49.74% (10,000B) 0x804841A: main (example.c:20)
| 
->39.79% (8,000B) 0x80483C2: g (example.c:5)
| ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x80483E2: f (example.c:11)
| | ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x8048431: main (example.c:23)
| |   
| ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x8048436: main (example.c:25)
|   
->09.95% (2,000B) 0x80483DA: f (example.c:10)
  ->09.95% (2,000B) 0x8048431: main (example.c:23)
```

So, you will get detailed information:

- WHO allocated the memory (functions: g(), f(), and main() in above example); you also get complete backtrace leading to allocating function,
- to WHICH data structure the memory did go (no data structures in above example),
- WHEN it happened,
- what PERCENTAGE of all allocated memory it is (g: 39.7%, f: 9.95%, main: 49.7%).

Here is [Massif manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)

You can track heap allocation as well as stack allocation (turned off by default).

**PS. I just read that you're on Windows. I will leave the answer though, because it gives a picture of what you can get from a possible tool.**

Comment: Massif did not support multi-core and make the program slow down too much, is there any other tool works with multi-core?

Comment: Also https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer (but note https://stackoverflow.com/a/49340854/560648). Example: https://cn.opendesktop.org/img//hive/content-pre1/122409-1.png

Answer (score 21):

Microsoft have well documented memory tracking functions. However, for some reason they are not really well-known in the developer community. These are CRT debug functions. Good starting point will be [CRT Debug Heap functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details).

Check the following links for more details

1. [Heap state reporting functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details#BKMK_Heap_State_Reporting_Functions)
2. [Tracking heap allocation requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details#BKMK_Track_Heap_Allocation_Requests).  Probably this is the functionality that you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, probably _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince is all he is looking for.

Answer (score 19):

For a generic C++ memory tracker you will need to overload the following:

```
global operator new
global operator new []
global operator delete
global operator delete []
any class allocators
any in-place allocators
```

The tricky bit is getting useful information, the overloaded operators only have size information for allocators and memory pointers for deletes. One answer is to use macros. I know. Nasty. An example - place in a header which is included from all source files:

```
#undef new

void *operator new (size_t size, char *file, int line, char *function);
// other operators

#define new new (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
```

and create a source file with:

```
void *operator new (size_t size, char *file, int line, char *function)
{
  // add tracking code here...
  return malloc (size);
}
```

The above only works if you don't have any operator new defined at class scope. If you do have some at class scope, do:

```
#define NEW new (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
```

and replace 'new type' with 'NEW type', but that requires changing a lot of code potentially.

As it's a macro, removing the memory tracker is quite straightforward, the header becomes:

```
#if defined ENABLED_MEMORY_TRACKER
#undef new

void *operator new (size_t size, char *file, int line, char *function);
// other operators

#define NEW new (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
#else
#define NEW new
#endif
```

and the implementation file:

```
#if defined ENABLED_MEMORY_TRACKER
void *operator new (size_t size, char *file, int line, char *function)
{
  // add tracking code here...
  return malloc (size);
}
endif
```

Comment: I needed to change `#define NEW new ((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__, (char*)__FUNCTION__)` on CygWin and Win 7 and as pointed out to me on *CodeReview* `size_t` is defined in multiple headers so `std::size_t` should be more preferable.

Comment: In this solution, be sure that your tracking code does not itself allocate memory on the heap (including STL containers) or the program will go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** to the answer of @Skizz

Since C++20, we can use [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) instead of macros like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

(As this is a major simplification, I believe that it deserves a seperate answer).

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode, you can use Instruments to track allocations, VM usage, and several other parameters. Mostly popular among iOS developers, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, you can use the code profiling tool Shark to do this, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

"A graphical representation of the heap over time" - close to what you are looking for is implemented in [Intel(R) Single Event API](https://github.com/01org/IntelSEAPI/wiki), details can be found in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1055834/Cross-platform-Visual-Memory-Tracker) (its rather big to put it here). [image: Memory block allocations over time]

It shows you timeline of per-block-size allocations and allows to add additional mark up to your code to understand the whole picture better.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio IDE has built-in heap profiling support (since 2015), which is probably the easiest to start with. It has graphical views of heap usage over time, and can track allocations by function/method.

- [Measure memory usage in Visual Studio](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/profiling/memory-usage.md)

[image: heap profiling]

The CRT also has debug and profile support, which is more detailed and more low-level. You could track the data and plot the results using some other tool:

- [CRT Debug Heap Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2019)

In particular, look at `_CrtMemCheckpoint` and related functions.

Comment: I can't figure how to make this work, it looks like this fails when using in a software that uses lots of memory (>1GB).

Comment: How does it fail? I was profiling a process just today which had allocated 12GB of memory. It's not arbitrarily limited.